# Local PC can't read socket of other PC in the same network

Tags: java, sockets, networking, local

I'm testing Java socket read/write basic example from Oracle.com

It can read/write if I run both server and client in the same machine.
But it doesn't work when it is to be read from other PC.

This is how they are connected via the same hub.
Internet->local network->hub->PC1 and PC2

PC1 is a server, running KnockKnockServer.java.
PC2 is a client, running KnockKnockClient.java.

Everything is same as default KnockKnockClient.java, but this:

```
    kkSocket = new Socket("PC1", 18090);
```

But I got "Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: PC1" error.

I opened same port in Kaspersky program in PC1 and firewall in PC2. 
Even if I turned off Kaspersky and firewall in PC1, it shows the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: How can I know it is a valid DNS name? BTW, PC1 can access all local network and Internet.

Comment: Can you use the IP address of the PC1? First, see if you can ping PC1. If you can reach PC1, create the socket using the IP address. This should tell you if the problem with the DNS/machine name or something more fundamental.

Comment: OK, PC2 is able to ping PC1 (time = 1ms); I used PC1 IP address. But why it is not able to read the socket of PC1?

Comment: OK, I found PC1 is not able to ping PC2...!!!

Comment: @user1098761: it's quite common for a firewall to specifically block ping packets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an IP address instead of the remote hostname:

```
kkSocket = new Socket("192.168.0.1", 18090);
```

Windows networks typically use [WINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service) for hostname resolution, rather than [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) - most home networks don't even have a DNS server. That allows Windows itself to find remote services (e.g. shares) by name, but most applications still require a proper DNS infrastructure for that to work.

Alternatively, you might want to edit the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to associate the IP addresses of any hosts on your network with their names.